# How to execute javascript code in success function of $ajax method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I'm having following code snippet. I've put the comment before the code which is not getting executed.

```
$(document).on('click', '#disable_url', function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = new Array();

    $("input:checked:not(#ckbCheckAll)").each(function() {
      items.push($(this).val());
    });

    var str = $("#user_filter").serialize();    
    var str = decodeURIComponent(str);

    var user_status = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      //user_status.push($("#"+items[i]).val());
      user_status.push($("#"+items[i]).val().replace(/'/g,''));
    }      

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "manage_users.php?op=disable_bulk_users&items="+items+"&options="+str+"&user_status="+user_status,
      dataType: 'json',  
      success: function(data) {
        var redirect_link = data.href;
        window.location.href = redirect_link;
      }          
    });
/*The below code is not getting executed. It is expected to be executed upon the success response from PHP file otherwise not*/
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { alert("Nibble");
      var status = 'enable'; 
      id = items[i];
      $('#user_status_'+id).html('<img src="{/literal}{$control_img_url}{literal}disable.png" border="0" alt="Enable User" width="20" height="20" />');
      $('#user_status_'+id).attr('title','Enable User');
      $('#user_status_'+id).attr('onClick', "change_user_status('"+module_url+"', '"+op+"', '"+id+"', '"+status+"');return false;");
    }
/*The non calling code ends here*/ 
      })
```

Everything from request to success response and redirection of page is working fine but I'm not able to execute the code upon receiving success response from PHP file. If the success response is not received then this code should not get executed. Can you help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If once the request is returned successfully, you're redirecting the user, when exactly do you expect the code to be executed?

Comment: @Lix:Actually if you notice closely I'm changing some HTML code. This change of HTML is expected to be done upon success response and the page also needs to be redirected.

Comment: So why not simply execute the code before the request? Or even inside the success callback before the redirect...

Comment: @Lix:Can you demonstrate with the code please?

Comment: @js - An example of executing the code inside the success callback is [contained in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19345422/558021) to this post. Executing it before the request would entail simply placing the loop code above the `$.ajax` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have this part:

```
  success: function(data) {
    var redirect_link = data.href;
    window.location.href = redirect_link;
  }
```

Naturally, this is a success `callback`. When the request was completed and your browser receives the response of success, the function will be executed. If you want to execute anything else inside your callback, just write your code into the function.

Also, if you redirect the browser, then do not expect your HTML to be visibly changed, as you will not see any change, because the redirect is *instant*. Use the `setTimeout` function to **delay** the redirect.